# Why don't properties get automatically synthesized

Tags: objective-c, properties

maybe this is a silly question. Every time I make a `@property` I have to `@synthesize` it. But this makes no sense the only thing you can do with a `@property(whatever) Type* property` is to do `@synthesize property` in the implementation file. So why are both needed? Why isn't the compiler generating the getter/setter methods automagically without me having to write `@synthesize property`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the current production compilers, the default -- the case without `@synthesize` -- is to do nothing and then warn if an implementation isn't provided.

`@synthesize` is automatic in the latest versions of the LLVM 2.0 compiler.

`@dynamic` **is not required** when implementing the setter/getter yourself.   `@dynamic` is used when dynamically providing the implementations at runtime.  That is, `@dynamic foo;` combined with `@property <type> foo;` will cause the compiler *not to warn* if you don't provide a `-foo` and `-setFoo:` implementation.

Note that you can also use `@synthesize propertyName = instanceVariableName;` to use a specific, differently named, instance variable as the backing store.

`@property` in the interface very much is short hand for the getter/setter method declarations.  It also carries more metadata (retain, assign, etc..) that is leveraged by the compiler during `@synthesize`.

And, as  always, an `atomic` property doesn't really help with thread safety.

Answer (score 2):

It is just historically so that current compiler requires that. In XCode 4 those @synthesize won't be required anymore (as per WWDC videos, hope I do not violate NDA here)...

Answer (score 1):

`@synthesize` is not the only option. `@dynamic property` is also possible.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about dynamic.

Comment: You can also implement the getter/setter yourself.

Answer (score 0):

@synthesize is not the only option; there is also @dynamic, which means you will implement the methods yourself. [Redacted; see bbum's answer for more detail.]

Comment: further discussion of the differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160498/synthesize-vs-dynamic-what-are-the-differences

Comment: Thanks. It still seems strange to me though. If I implement the getters and setters myself I can just copy the function definitions into the header files without using @property declaration. :)

Comment: This answer is generally correct, but gets a number of details wrong.  See my answer.

Comment: You better not get a compiler warning if you add @dynamic! That is the whole point! (Checking) And, in fact, you do not get a compiler warning.  Of course, you'll get a runtime exception if you don't dynamically inject an implementation.

Comment: @bbum I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that (now-removed) comment.

Comment: No worries -- it seems to be a very common point of confusion.  I'm curious as to where it is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

As of Xcode 4.4 this is now what happens. Synthesize is no longer explicitly required.