# Under what conditions is @synthesize automatic in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, llvm, synthesize

**Under what conditions is @synthesize automatic in Objective-c?**

Perhaps when using LLVM 3.0 and up? From reading around the net it seems like `@synthesize` is unnecessary starting with Xcode 4. However I'm using Xcode 4 and receiving warnings when I don't `@synthesize` a property.

Some of the responses to [Why don't properties get automatically synthesized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068771/why-dont-properties-get-automatically-synthesized) seem to imply @synthesize can be omitted at some point under some circumstances.

[Another (old) reference](http://www.mcubedsw.com/blog/index.php/site/comments/new_objective-c_features/) hinting that `@synthesize` might be automatic at some point in the future.

Comment: Do you have a link for where @synthesize is described as unnecessary?

Comment: Perhaps he has seen some information about the currently-under-NDA Xcode 4.4 and has become confused about version numbers.

Comment: @bneely added a link. Perhaps I'm misreading "@synthesize is automatic in the latest versions of the LLVM 2.0 compiler".

Comment: @robmayoff more like I've been reading potentially outdated information :-)  See the links above.

Answer (score 25):

As of clang 3.2 (circa February 2012), "default synthesis" (or "auto property synthesis") of Objective-C properties is provided by default. It's essentially as described in the blog post you originally read: [http://www.mcubedsw.com/blog/index.php/site/comments/new_objective-c_features/](http://web.archive.org/web/20131006070703/http://www.mcubedsw.com/blog/index.php/site/comments/new_objective-c_features/) (except that that post describes the feature as "enabled, then disabled"; I don't know if that's an issue with Xcode or if the clang developers themselves have gone back and forth on the question).

As far as I know, the only case in which properties will *not* be default-synthesized in clang 3.2 is when those properties have been inherited from a protocol. Here's an example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol P
@property int finicky;
@end

@interface A : NSObject <P>
@property int easygoing;
@end

@implementation A
@end

int main() { A *a = [A new]; a.easygoing = 0; a.finicky = 1; }
```

If you compile this example, you'll get a warning:

```
test.m:11:17: warning: auto property synthesis will not synthesize property
      declared in a protocol [-Wobjc-protocol-property-synthesis]
@implementation A
                ^
test.m:4:15: note: property declared here
@property int finicky;
              ^
1 warning generated.
```

and if you run it, you'll get an error from the runtime:

```
objc[45820]: A: Does not recognize selector forward:: (while forwarding setFinicky:)
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Answer (score 14):

As of Xcode 4.4, if you don't write `@synthesize` or `@dynamic` for a property. the compiler acts as though you had written `@synthesize property = _property`.

Prior to Xcode 4.4, you must do one of the following things for each property or else the compiler will issue a warning and you will get a runtime error.  In Xcode 4.4 or later, you may do any of the following things instead of letting the compiler automatically synthesize the property accessors and instance variable.

1. Use the `@synthesize` directive.
2. Use the `@dynamic` directive and somehow provide the property getter and (if necessary) setter at runtime.
3. Explicitly write the property getter method and, if the property is `readwrite`, the property setter method.

Note that you can use the `@synthesize` directive (or the `@dynamic` directive) and *also* explicitly provide the getter and/or setter methods.  But `@synthesize` provides them if you omit them.

Comment: If you provide BOTH the getter and the setter, then you lose the automatic ivar, right?

Answer (score 13):

From the [New Features in Xcode 4.4](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_4.html) document:

> Objective-C @properties are synthesized by default when not explicitly implemented.

So @synthesize is automatic by default starting from Xcode 4.4 with the LLVM 4.0 Compiler.

Comment: Note that automatic synthesis is not supported for 32-bit Mac OS X.

Answer (score 12):

Also, synthesize will not be automatic if you have implemented the setter AND getter manually. So if you wonder why you can't access _someVariable, having declared @property (...) SomeType someVariable, then it is because you have implemented the setSomeVariable: and someVariable methods.

Answer (score 5):

You can turn off the synthesize warnings by clicking on the project name in the Project Navigator on the left then click All Cobined in Build Settings and then search for synthesize. That should be set to No.

Comment: Actually this is the only correct answer, an old answer. The rest goes to deep. Be sure to check the settings of all your targets, if you have multiple