# -fobjc-arc is not supported with fragile abi

Tags: c++, xcode, dylib

I have this line of code:

```
GetVolParmsInfoBuffer volumeParms;
HParamBlockRec pb;
```

And I included this header:

```
#include </System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/Files.h>
```

But still the compiler throws the error that `HParamBlockRec` is unknown type.

In a other project with the same files everything works fine, even without including the `Files.h` header.
Is there anything I'm missing?

**Update**
I was able to fix the error by setting the architecture to 32-Bit.

But now I'm getting this build error:

```
error: -fobjc-arc is not supported with fragile abi
```

I searched a little and it's been sait that switching to the LLVM GGC 4.2 compiler would help, but it doesn't.

Right now my build settings are:

- 32-bit Intel
- Mac OSX 10.7 SDK
- Build active architecture only **Yes**
- Mach-O Type is set to **Dynamic Library**

I'm very unfimiliar with coding in XCode. So it would be great if you could help me out here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, ARC is simply not available on 32-bit OS X. Apparently Apple has decided that all new development should have moved to x86-64 by now, so all the sweet new Objective-C 2.0 features — not just ARC, but also `-fobjc-nonfragile-abi`, [container literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html), object subscripting, [default synthesis of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11767553/1424877)... — are implemented only for 64-bit OS X (and of course for 32-bit iOS).

So, if you're trying to produce a fat binary containing code for both 32- and 64-bit versions of OS X, you'll have to limit yourself to Objective-C 1.0 features and/or hack up your codebase with #ifdefs. This isn't fair, but it's true. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't include individual headers from a framework. Use the umbrella header instead:

```
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>
```

Also, per [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000107-CH3g-C002500) `HParamBlockRec` is not available in 64-bit. You will need to find a modern substitute for the parameter block-based function you’re using.

As for the `-fobjc-arc` warning, make sure you have the *Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting* (`$CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC`) build setting set to *No* (`NO`).

Comment: Then you should include more details in your question (base SDK, deployment target, Xcode version, OS X version you’re building on). I’ve also added a compatibility note to my answer.