# Why properties still work without synthesize?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I have in .h

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *yourMom;
```

Then in .m

No synthesize!
direct access in viewdidload:

```
_yourMom = @"Sally";
```

This works without synthesizing. Why?

Comment: `_yourMom` is automatically synthesized by the compiler, but you can custom it anyway you want

Comment: Ah. so it is auto-synthesized. good to know thanks Tj3n

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Under what conditions is @synthesize automatic in Objective-c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368676/under-what-conditions-is-synthesize-automatic-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Objective-C @properties are synthesized by default when not explicitly implemented.

> Unless you specify otherwise, the synthesized instance variable has the same name as the property, but with an underscore prefix. For a property called firstName, for example, the synthesized instance variable will be called _firstName.

Please read this  [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) from Apple. It has comprehensive information that you need.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14919331)

Comment: @JanChrbolka thank you for your recommendation. I have just edit my answer :)

Comment: @martinlee put comment in question this kind of answer dont update answer separately.