# Why @synthetize has to be added manually?

Tags: objective-c

When I declare a `@property` it is obvious that I would like to use it later. For some reasons declaring `@property` is not enough and I have to tell compiler to `@synthetize` it in every `.m` file. Because of this every `.m` file in my projects starts with `@synthetize`.

Why they did not do it in a C# way, where just declaration is enough and compiler do the rest?

Comment: AppCode can do it. Xcode cann't by default.

Comment: Do you mean IDE from JetBrains?

Comment: yes I do. (And some characters more to achieve 15 symbols in comment :)

Comment: In the near future it _likely_ won't be necessary to type `@synthesize` anymore due to changes in LLVM: http://www.mcubedsw.com/blog/index.php/site/comments/new_objective-c_features/

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs: The note there suggests that this has been removed indefinitely: «NB: This feature is no longer available and so should not be used. It may re-appear at some point but in the mean time we sadly have to write our @synthesize statements.», and [bbum indicates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4070382/) that it was part of LLVM 2.0; since we are now on v3 and climbing, it's unclear that default `@synthesize` actually represents the future.

Answer (score 4):

By making `@synthesize` optional, you are free to implement your getter and setter methods in any way you choose.

You can find more information in Apple's [Declared Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) documentation, particularly the section titled "Property Implementation Directives".

Comment: Couldn't `@synthesize` be the default, though, unless a getter and/or setter is explicitly implemented, or `@dynamic` is specified instead?

Comment: IIRC if you use `@synthesize` and still implement a getter and/or setter, the one you implement will be used instead. This can be useful for synthesizing a getter and providing a custom setter for instance. But then it doesn't help explaining why `@synthesize` has to be written manually all the time ;)

Comment: yeah, what was the reason not to choose default implementation of @synthetize which can be overridden by user?

Answer (score 0):

You get standard Accessors almost for free and its possible to roll your own Getters / Setter if necessary.