# What is common case for @dynamic usage?

Tags: iphone, dynamic, properties, nsmanagedobject, synthesizer

There is previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160498/synthesize-vs-dynamic-what-are-the-differences) about difference of @synthesize and @dynamic.

I wanna to know more about dynamic from the perspective of how to use @dynamic usually.

Usually we use @dynamic together with NSManagedObject

```
// Movie.h
@interface Movie : NSManagedObject {
}
@property (retain) NSString* title;
@end

// Movie.m
@implementation Movie
@dynamic title;
@end
```

Actually there are no generated getter/setter during compiler time according to understanding of @dynamic, so it is necessary to implement your own getter/setter.

My question is that in this NSManagedObject case, what is the rough implementation of getter/setter in super class NSManagedObject ?

Except above case, how many other cases to use @dynamic ?

Thanks,

Comment: As Justin already said, the key take-away is that `@dynamic` ***EXPLICITLY STOPS*** the compiler from making it's own accessors.

If you don't have `@dynamic` (i.e., if you have nothing), "anything could happen" on the day, with different versions, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@dynamic` indicates to the compiler that you plan to provide your own implementation for the accessor(s), even if the compiler can't currently see them. If you omit `@dynamic` and don't use `@synthesize`, one of two things will happen:

1. If you've only provided half an accessor (for instance, a getter without a setter on a `readwrite` property), or you're using GCC, the compiler will warn you.
2. <strike>If you're using Clang to compile your code, proper accessors will be automatically generated for you.</strike> (Synthesize-by-default is not officially supported.)

`@dynamic` is therefore useful to prevent the compiler from doing either of the above. This might also come in handy if you implement a property in a very dynamic way, like with runtime functions, but that's rarely necessary.

Comment: Sorry, that was an experimental feature that they've since removed. Synthesized properties now need an explicit `@synthesize`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I think you can restore you #2 point. Properties are now synthesized by default afaik (also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11666008/6827)