# What does @dynamic do in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, dynamic

Objective-C has a feature called @dynamic.

Google only lists results about dynamic typing.

I rarely see this in code and I don't understand what it is used for. Can anyone explain me this? Thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524954/what-is-common-case-for-dynamic-usage/4524983#4524983 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160498/synthesize-vs-dynamic-what-are-the-differences

Comment: Meaning that those two questions are also duplicates of this one and eachother, making them interchangeable. I'll accept the answer and close this. :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`@dynamic` means “my class will figure out how to respond to this at runtime.” Uses a runtime mechanism for an object to intercept messages it normally wouldn’t respond to. In the case where a Core Data db is used to store persistent data, NSManagedObject turns these into calls to `-valueForKey:` and `-setValueForKey:`.

Take a look at [Lecture 12](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/lectures/Lecture%2012.pdf) (Fall 2010) of Stanford's iPhone development course.

Comment: But how can my code add properties to an object at runtime?

Comment: check out `<objc/runtime.h>` and `NSObject.h` file

Comment: @Time Machine: `@dynamic` doesn't necessarily mean the property will be added at run time, it just a way of saying to the compiler "I know I have declared the property but not implemented it in this class, but I know it will be there at run time".  It could be as simple as the implementation is known to be provided by the super class.

Comment: @JeremyP I never said it does. I just asked how to do it. :)

Comment: @Time Machine: Sorry, I thought you were just asking because you couldn't see how to add properties at run time and therefore thought @dynamic is pointless. My point was that, yes there are ways to literally add properties at run time but also, it can be as simple as subclassing.

Comment: You can look into implementing getter and setter methods manually 
-(id)setPropertyName :(PropertyType)newName
-(id)propertyName

Comment: @JeremyP I really like your explanation more than Penang's. You should post it in an answer.