# Objective c property issue

Tags: objective-c, ios5, properties, undeclared-identifier

In my `Settings.h` file I have the line

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray * connections;
```

Also in the `Settings.m` file there are importing:

```
#import "Settings.h"
```

and later I provide the implementation

```
- (NSArray*)connections 
{
    return connections;
}
- (void)setConnections:(NSArray*)_connections
{
    connections = _connections; 
    // do some more stuff
}
```

But both in getter and setter I get an error about `use of undeclared identifier 'connections'`
I have no idea what do I do wrong, so any of your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: By the way that is not how the setter for a nonatomic retained property looks! Expect unexpected memory problems.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to use `connections = [_connections retain];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are, quite correctly, trying to use an ivar (called `connections`) as a backing store for your property, also called `connections`;

To get it to work, you should simply declare an ivar like this:

```
// Settings.h

NSArray * connections;
```

It should go between the curly brackets of the class declaration, like this:

```
@interface MyClass : MySuperClass {
    NSArray *connections;
    // More ivars...
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSArray *connections;

@end
```

Comment: Yes, I've already added it and it worked :) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
in Settings.m 

@synthesize connections = _connections;

in setting.h
```

Answer (score -1):

In `Settings.h` add an instance variable `NSArray *connections;` (if it's not there already), then in `Settings.m` just below `@implementation` add this:

```
@dynamic connections;
```

Another option is to remove you accessors and go for `@synthesize connections;` instead of `dynamic` and the accessor methods will be created for you.

Comment: yes, it would be reasonable to remove my own accessors, but I have to specify few more actions in setter, which I didn't mention in here.

Comment: Hmm, when I add `@dynamic connections;` the error doesn't disappear.

Comment: Oh, no-no, I made a mistake :) Now, everything works great! Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the need for `@dynamic connections`?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know - I just tried to remove it and nothing changed, everything works like before

Comment: As I understand it `@dynamic` is needed in order to access `connections` as a property, e.g. in bindings or using `mySetting.connection` notation. From what I've read you use it when you want to write the property accessors yourself. As such, `[mySetting connections]` would work without the `@dynamic`, while `mySetting.connections` would not. I might be wrong on this though.

Comment: I thought that `@dynamic` is required if I'm going to define accessors later, e.g. in subclasses. What about notation, in my application I write `currentSettings.connections = [fields objectForKey:@"connections"];` and it works fine

Comment: Yes, I am obviously wrong here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4621968/222245 offers a pretty good description of `@dynamic`.

Comment: You know, probably you're not - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524954/what-is-common-case-for-dynamic-usage/4524983#4524983 :) As I got, it's just a question of your programming style