# @dynamic keyword meaning in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@synthesize vs @dynamic, what are the differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160498/synthesize-vs-dynamic-what-are-the-differences)

When we write any object like `@dynamic obj;`
we tell the compiler that we will fulfill accessor method for it, so where do we need to implement those methods?

If we implement accessor methods in same class in which we have declared @property then we dont even need use of `@dynamic`, like in header file:

```
@proprty (attribue) NSString *objStr;
```

and in .m:

```
- (NSString *)objStr { 
}

- (void)setObjStr:(NSString *)somestring {
}
```

Comment: Almost same question. See this [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4621968/1357776

Answer (score 9):

The `@dynamic` keyword tells the compiler that you will provide accessor methods dynamically at runtime.  This can be done using the Objective-C runtime functions.

Typically, you would use `@dynamic` with things like Core Data, where Core Data will provide the accessors based on the Core Data model.

You are correct that in most normal cases you would not use `@dynamic`.  Typically, you would just use `@property` or `@property` and `@synthesize`.