# Automatically @synthesized properties in Xcode 4.4

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.4

From the Xcode 4.4 release notes:

> The compiler automatically calls @synthesize by default for unimplemented @properties

What exactly does the new default synthesizer look like? Does it create a variable of the same name as the property (or does it prefix it with an underscore, which seems to be a good practice, but required extra typing so far)?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

the default is `@synthesize propertyName = _propertyName`

Comment: -1 for Apple. How do I override this behaviour? Why can't this horrible underscore convention go away and die?

Comment: @Sam you can always write your own synthesize, same as you did before 4.4. Whats wrong with this convention though?

Comment: Yes, but there doesn't seem to be any way to change the automatically generated `@synthesize`. Which is inconsistent with the behaviour of `@synthesize propertyName;`. Don't get me started on underscores, or this will degenerate into a religious war.

Comment: more reading on the subject: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html

Comment: @PawanSharma you can still use synthesize if you like, but why would you want to disable this?