# Using class extensions in xcode 4.4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.4

Since xcode 4.4 you don't need to `@synthesize` properties anymore ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666008/automatic-synthesized-properties-in-xcode-4-4)), the compiler does it for you. So, why does the compiler complain

> use of the undeclared identifier _aVar

in my `viewDidLoad` method of `ViewControllerSubclass`:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (assign, nonatomic) int aVar;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.aVar = 5;
    NSLog(@"Super value: %d", _aVar);
}
@end

@interface ViewControllerSubclass : ViewController
@end

@interface ViewControllerSubclass ()
@property (assign, nonatomic) int aVar;
@end

@implementation ViewControllerSubclass
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Subclass value: %d", _aVar);
}
@end
```

If I move everything to the one file instead of 4 separate files for the respective interfaces and implementations, the compiler instead complains that `_aVar` is private. But _aVar should have been automatically synthesized in my `ViewControllerSubclass`.

Still keeping everything in 1 file, if I move the initial property declaration to a class extension:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (assign, nonatomic) int aVar;
@end
```

The build still fails saying that `_aVar` is private.

If I go back to the 4 file setup for the respective interfaces and implementations xcode builds without even a warning.

If I then run the code:

```
[[[ViewControllerSubclass alloc] init] view];
```

the log statements in the above examples print out the following:

> Super value: 0
>
> Subclass value: 5

It makes sense that `NSLog(@"Super value: %d", _aVar);` produced a result of `0` because this variable is supposed to be private to the superclass. But then, why does `NSLog(@"Subclass value: %d", _aVar);` produce a result of `5`??

This is all very odd.

Comment: From what I understand this is a feature that's part of the Apple LLVM 4.0 compiler, and not the Xcode IDE. What compiler are you using in your project?

Comment: Yes, but xcode4.4 uses this compiler by default.

Comment: So the configuration that builds but generates the odd log statements is the one where you have declared the property in the superclass's public interface and the subclass's extension?

Comment: No, the only 'configuration' that builds is the one where both properties are declared in the class extensions for both the super and subclasses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you make the superclass declaration public, the compiler won't attempt to re-synthesize the property; it assumes that's been taken care of in the superclass. Thus, `_aVar` is not in scope anywhere in the subclass. It's private anyway, so even when you put them all in the same file that's why you see those errors.

However when you make the superclass property declaration inside the class extension, the compiler will auto-synthesize the property for both the superclass and the subclass. This ends up with both classes having private instance variables _aVar (with two distinct addresses). However, when the superclass `viewDidLoad` method sets the property, the method invokes the subclass's accessors, which set the value of the subclass's private _aVar variable, and not the superclass's. So that explains why you see the superclass value not changing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My question was really made up of a number of different questions and this answers them all.

Answer (score 6):

You are confusing several different issues, and I'm somewhat confused when you talk about jumping between files and you don't specify where your errors are happening.

Anyway, there is the issue of instance variable visibility.  If you declare your iVars within the interface scope, they are, by default, protected.

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
    int protectedInt;
@private
    int privateInt;
@public
    int publicInt;
}
@end
```

When you synthesize iVars, the instance variables themselves are private, unless you explicitly specify them.

Methods will always fire on the most derived implementation.

Now, when you call this...

```
[[[ViewControllerSubclass alloc] init] view];
```

You will allocate a subclass, initialize, and cause the view to be loaded.  This code will execute...

```
@implementation ViewControllerSubclass
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Subclass value: %d", _aVar);
}
@end
```

The first thing it does is call the base class implementation...

```
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.aVar = 5;
    NSLog(@"Super value: %d", _aVar);
}
@end
```

Of course, it calls super, but that part's not important here.  The next line assigns 5 to self.iVar.  But, which iVar?  It calls the property setter **method** on this object.  What type is this instance?  It's a `ViewControllerSubclass`.  Since you have given both your base class and its subclass the same name (and declared the property as part of the class extension), they each have their own private-scope instance variable .

However, a method is called on the most derived implementation.  Thus, self.iVar will set the instance variable of the subclass.  The instance variable for the base class remains unchanged.

When you `NSLog` the value, you are accessing the private instance variable of the base class, which has not been changed.

Now, after the base class `viewDidLoad` finishes, we get the code running for the subclass.  It logs the value of its private instance variable, which was changed as a result of the base class calling the property setter.  So, it will now print it's value, which is 5.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your setup and could replicate your error. I came to the following conclusion:

You need to declare your `@property` in a `.h` file. If you want a private variable, declare it in `.m` in the category `@interface` (the one with the parentheses).

Comment: That's the thing. In the final example above, aVar is declared in the .m for both classes so, why does the subclass print a value of 5?