# Objective C - Custom @synthesize?

Tags: objective-c, properties, getter, synthesizer

Is it possible to somehow create a custom @synthesize to generate custome getter, setters ??

For example:

```
@interface
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyObject *object;
@end

@implementation
@lazyInitialize object;
@end
```

And then somehow define @lazyInitialize to generate a lazy initializer method

```
//@lazyInitialize

- (id)"property name"
{
   if (!"property name")
   {
      "property name" = [[["property name" class] alloc] init];
   }
   return "property name";
}
```

Comment: Not exactly a solution, but probably of interst: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160498/synthesize-vs-dynamic-what-are-the-differences

Comment: Might this type of statement be of help? @property (copy,setter=setDefaultTitle:) NSString* title;

Comment: Stefan that seems really interesting. Can setDefaultTitle be a class method in another Class?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I suppose, you need to provide a method signature of your own class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something different, though. I wouldn't have thought of this more than a couple days ago, but I happened to be reading [Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html). In the post linked, he discussed how he made a `#define` macro that would "generate" the entire class for a singleton into wherever you called the macro from. You can [download his code](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/SynthesizeSingleton.h.zip) for this (may give ideas on your own implementation).

Perhaps something like (*Warning: Untested Code Ahead*):

```
#define SYNTHESIZE_LAZY_INITIALIZER_FOR_OBJECT(objectName, objectType) \
\
- (objectType *)objectName \
{ \
    if(!objectName) \
    { \
          objectName = [[objectType alloc] init]; \
    } \
    return objectName; \
} \
\
- (void)set##objectName:(objectType *)value \
{ \
    [value retain]; \
    [objectName release]; \
    objectName = value; \
}
```

would work? I apologize that I don't have time to properly test it for you, so take that as fair warning that this isn't a quick copy/paste solution. Sorry about that. Hopefully it is still useful! ;)

---

**Example Usage**

This should work, again *Warning: Untested Code Ahead*:

Header

```
// ....
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
    NSObject *someObj;
}
@end
```

Implementation

```
@implementation SomeClass
// ....
SYNTHESIZE_LAZY_INITIALIZER_FOR_OBJECT(someObj, NSObject);
// ....
@end
```

Comment: Interesting, but how can I use this?

Comment: @Rayan, pure Objective-C looks way better. Sure, there is no pure way to define a generic getter or setter, but C-macrosses (at my taste) are worse than nothing. Once I got a project with such code for support and refactoring - removing such macrosses was the best refactoring ever :) The code became readable.

Comment: Why are there back-slashes in there? What do they represent?

Comment: @aryaxt: They escape newlines to make them part of the `#define`. Without the backslashes, the first newline would be seen as the end of the single-line `#define` statement.

Comment: @Gobra Yeah, I would concur. That is actually why I *don't* use the code from that blog. I would rather deal with writing the code each time and having a template to work from rather than use this. I proposed it as a possible alternative to the standard "no" answer, not necessarily as the de facto answer to this question. Personally, I would rather just have a snippet of code that I copy/paste when needed than do this as my solution.

Comment: @Ryan Can you explain how I can use the code you provided? where do I write the code? I defined it in my prefic.pch and I try something like this in my viewDidLoad of a viewController.  SYNTHESIZE_LAZY_INITIALIZER_FOR_OBJECT ("WebServiceClient", "webService");, and I get the following error "expected expression before ')' token.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is really interesting, but my purpose of creating a custom @synthesize was to make my code cleaner, and unfortunately this is not clean at all :(. Anyways great answer.

Comment: @aryaxt Judging from the comments, everyone else agrees with you (including myself), so definitely no hard feelings. Sorry it isn't more applicable to your situation (or any for that matter!).

Answer (score 2):

`@synthesize` in Objective-C works similarly to automatic property syntax in C#, in that both generate the minimal required syntax for creating property getters/setters. In both languages, if you want custom functionality, you need to implement them manually.

I really like [Ryan Wersal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849764/objective-c-custom-synthesize/5850166#5850166) of using a `#define` to roll your own macro. You'd still have to write the method yourself, but you only do it once.