# change from @synthesize to @dynamic to use RestKit Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit

I want to use Core Data support for RestKit but when I change @synthesize to @dynamic, I've lost all getters and setters and I use them across all my app, in almost every model. What can I do to get my app up and running again without having to change all the code?

I was thinking of implementing all the getters and setters by myself but I think it should be a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: And are you subclassing NSManagedObject now? The getters and setters have disappeared because they can no longer be dynamically generated.

Comment: Yes I'm subclassing NSManagedObject on my models and I was expecting this problem to happen. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: It sounds like you have a configuration problem with your core data setup. This should not happen normally. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160498/synthesize-vs-dynamic-what-are-the-differences) is an explanation of the difference.

Comment: I already read that article. From there I understand that I will not have the setter and getter methods available on the objects. I'm I wrong?