# Error accessing generated ivars when I override setters and getters in Modern Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, getter-setter

I know now the new Objective-C compiler lets you not need to synthesize your properties anymore.  I have one file that has two classes in it.  My .h for a simple helper class looks like this:

```
@interface ViewFrameModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect frame;

- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view frame:(CGRect)frame;

@end
```

In the same .h file, for my other class (class 2), I have:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewFrameModel *viewFrameModel;
```

In class 2.m, I can do this:

```
- (void)setViewFrameModel:(ViewFrameModel *)viewFrameModel {
    _viewFrameModel = viewFrameModel;        
    [self pushViewFrameModel:viewFrameModel];
}
```

This works fine with no complaints from the compiler, however, when I add this:

```
- (ViewFrameModel *)viewFrameModel {
    return _viewFrameModel;
}
```

I get two complaints, one on the first method `setViewFrameModel`:

> "Use of undeclared identifier _viewFrameModel, did you  mean viewFrameModel"

And the other on return `_viewFrameModel`:

> "Use of undeclared identifier _viewFrameModel, did you  mean viewFrameModel"
>   "Reference to local variable viewFrameModel' declared in enclosing context"

Why do I get these errors when I add in the

```
- (ViewFrameModel *)viewFrameModel {
    return _viewFrameModel;
}
```

method?  I want to override this method with some custom info, but it's complaining at me :-.  Thoughts?  TIA.

Comment: "I know now the new Objective-C compiler lets you not need to synthesize your properties anymore" - **Thank you** for saying "compiler" and not "Xcode". Finally, somebody!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you override both the setter and the getter, the compiler will not automatically create the instance variable for you anymore. You can add it to your class implementation like so:

```
@implementation ClassName {
    ViewFrameModel *_viewFrameModel;
}
...
@end
```

Comment: Do you have any references for this? Where did you read this? Thanks.

Comment: @sole007 I think I saw it in the modern objective C WWDC video from some years back.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the results of some testing I did last year: [iOS automatic @synthesize without creating an ivar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933785/ios-automatic-synthesize-without-creating-an-ivar/12933956#12933956).

In short, you need to use @synthesize or declare an iVar explicitly.

Comment: You do not *need* to use @synthesize. You can declare your own ivar instead.

Comment: Huh, I would say you don't need to declare iVars, you can use @ synthesize. I guess it's what you prefer.

Comment: Before the latest compiler, `@synthesize` only synthesized the setter and getter methods, not the ivar. Since the OP is providing the methods, there is no need to use `@synthesize`. It is clearer, in this case, to add your own ivar. Why use `@synthesize` when the bulk of what it does isn't being used? But, in the end, with the latest compiler, `@synthesize` will work. My main objection was to your use of the word "need" since that is in fact not true. It's an option, not a need.

Comment: @rmaddy No, `@synthesize` has always generated an iVar if it was not present. I've written lots of `@synthesize prop = _prop;` lines without ever needing to explicitly declare an iVar. I understand your nit about the word 'need', I'll change the wording.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the answers:

If you override both the setter and the getter, the compiler will not create the instance variable for you.

Why? In that case, the compiler assumes that the property is dynamic: that it might be a property that relies on other properties for storage / computation, or that it will be created in other ways, for example, at runtime using Objective-C runtime functions.

To help the compiler understand the situation better there are two potential solutions:

```
@implementation Class
@synthesize property = _property;
...
@end
```

or

```
@implementation Class {
    PropertyClass *_property;
}
...
@end
```