# Adding a property to all of my UIControls

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicontrol

Im trying to make it so that every single `UIControl` in my application (`UIButton`, `UISlider`, etc) all have special extra properties that I add to them.

I tried to accomplish this by creating a `UIControl` Category and importing it where needed but I have issues.

Here is my code.

My `setSpecialproperty` method gets called but it seems to be getting called in an infinite loop until the app crashes.

Can you tell me what Im doing wrong or suggest a smarter way to add a property to all of my `UIControls`?

```
@interface UIControl (MyControl)
{

}
@property(nonatomic,strong) MySpecialProperty  *specialproperty;

-(void)setSpecialproperty:(MySpecialProperty*)param;
@end
```

////////

```
#import "UIControl+MyControl.h"

@implementation UIControl (MyControl)

-(void)setSpecialproperty:(MySpecialProperty*)param
{
    self.specialproperty=param;
}
```

///////////////

```
#import "UIControl+MyControl.h"

@implementation ViewController


UIButton *abutton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
MySpecialProperty *prop=[MySpecialProperty alloc]init];
[abutton setSpecialproperty:prop];
```

Comment: You don't need to create a setter method. The compiler already does that for you. Just call it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't add an iVar to UIControl via a category, you can add Associated Objects, which can be used to perform much the same function.

So, create a category on UIControl like this:

```
static char kControlNameKey;

- (void) setControlName: (NSString *) name
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kControlNameKey, name, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
}

- (NSString *) controlName
{
    return (NSString *)objc_getAssociatedObject(array, &kControlNameKey);
}
```

There's more to it than that, I guess you'll need to check if an association exists before setting a new one, otherwise it will leak, but this should give you a start.

See the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

`self.specialproperty=param` is exactly the same as calling `[self setSpecialproperty]` (see [here](http://qualitycoding.org/dot-notation/) for some *totally non biased* coverage of Obj-C dot notation), which makes your current usage infinitely recursive.

What you actually want to do is:

```
-(void)setSpecialproperty:(MySpecialProperty*)param
{
  _specialproperty = param;
}
```

Where `_specialproperty` is the implicitly created `ivar` for your property.

I'm assuming there's some reason why you've implemented your `setSpecialproperty` setter? Why not just use the one that is implicitly created for you?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you can not add a property to a category, you can add behavior (methods) but not properties or attributes, this can only be done to extensions, and you can not create extensions of the SDK classes

Comment: So what Im trying to do is impossible?

Comment: the way you're trying to do it, yes it is not possible, @VineetSinghRawat give you an option, it could seems a bit complicated but it is not, just read it carefully

Comment: this [article](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/06/associated-objects/) could be *more easy* to read than the Apple Doc

Answer (score -1):

use your method as

change your method name to

```
-(void)setSpecialproperty:(MySpecialProperty *)specialproperty

-(void)setSpecialproperty:(MySpecialProperty*)specialproperty
{
   if(_specialproperty!=specialproperty)
  _specialproperty = specialproperty;
}
```

and synthesize your specialProperty as

```
@synthesize specialproperty=_specialproperty;
```

Comment: Synthesizing the property is not strictly necessary (since Xcode 4.4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933785/ios-automatic-synthesize-without-creating-an-ivar)