# @synthesize behind the scenes

Tags: objective-c, properties, synthesize

When we create a property and defined a synthesize for it, the compiler automatically creates getters and setters methods, right?

Now, If I execute this command:

```
@property(nonatomic) int value;

@synthesize value;

value = 50;
```

What happens:

The compiler saves the value '50' in the property?

```
property (nonatomic) int value; // Here is the stored value 50!
```

or the compiler creates a variable behind the scenes with the same name of the property like this:

```
interface myClass: NSObject {
    int value; // Here is the stored value 50!
}
```

What actually happens and what the alternatives listed above is correct?

Comment: I don't see why it would create a variable behind the scenes, but I have no idea really. Why do you ask?

Comment: @adam10603 I asked this sort of thing, because I'm starting to learn about dynamic, and setting a property dynamic you have to do this manually, now that already know how works synthesize, already have a better idea of how the dynamic works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably semantics, but `@synthesize` is no longer required for properties. The compiler does it automatically.

But to answer your question, the compiler creates an instance variable to store the value for the property.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger value;
// an instance variable NSInteger _value; will be created in the interface.
```

You can use the instance variable in your own code if you need to access it without going through the property. This is common when overriding a setter, like so:

```
- (void)setValue:(NSInteger)value {
    _value = value;
    // custom code
}
```

Comment: @property generates the instance variable and the setter and getter methods, not a bridge. When you access a property like `object.property;` the compiler translates it to `[object property];` or `object.property = value;` into `[object setProperty:value];` - it's more of a syntactic short cut than a bridge.

Comment: To extend on you answer, the `@synthesize` call can actually set the name of the ivar, e.g. `@synthesize x = myX`. The important thing to understand is that the property is a setter and a getter, 2 methods. A property doesn't have to have an ivar at all.

Comment: This is true, and it can be tricky to know which cases will generate an ivar and which won't. This answer has a pretty good summary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933785/ios-automatic-synthesize-without-creating-an-ivar