# Add @propertys to Core Data class

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I made few classes via Core Data. And I need some additional `@property`s for one of that classes in runtime. This `@property`s are responsible for download progress and I don't want to store them in Core Data DB. I tried to use a separate extension class:

```
@interface MyClass ()

    {
        CGFloat _downloadProgress;
        NSInteger _downloadErrorCounter;
        BOOL _downloadAllStuff;
        BOOL _downloadUserCanceled;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat downloadProgress;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger downloadErrorCounter;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL downloadAllStuff;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL downloadUserCanceled;

@end
```

But private variables are not visible out of MyClass, and `@property`s compile all right, but in runtime i get `-[MyClass setDownloadErrorCounter:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.
Can anyone suggest me some solution?

Comment: Do you have @dynamic in you m-file?

Comment: Did you `@synthesize` the setters and getters? Even in Modern Objective-C were you don't need to `@synthesize` anymore it appears that it's necessary to synthesize in NSManagedObject subclasses. The compiler should show you a warning that you have to define a setter and getter for your properties too.

Comment: No i haven't. It's Core Data, so i can't change Core Data classes. And I use a new file MyClass_Download.h to declare properties. Where can I synthesize them?

Comment: You don't need to declare private variables like that. `@property` will create the `_...` private variable for you and synthesise it properly too. All you need is the `@property` line. Why don't you make a new class which is a subclass of the core data class? Then you wouldn't have to worry about your new properties being overwritten.

Comment: @ThomasClayson: That does not work (or is at least difficult). NSManagedObject subclasses *must* be initialized using `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`, and even if you call that from a custom subclass, it returns an object of the entities class (I just tried it). I don't say that it is impossible, but it is not straightforward either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest solution (if you don't want to modify the Xcode generated class files) is to add the properties to the Core Data model and define the
properties as *transient*. Transient properties are not saved to the store file.

Another option is to use a tool like "mogenerator", which generates two class files for each
entity, one for the Core Data properties (which is overwritten if the the model changes),
and one for your custom properties (which is *not* overwritten).

**Update:** Starting with **Xcode 7,** Xcode creates both a class and
a category for each managed object subclass, compare [NSManagedObject subclass property in category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063965/nsmanagedobject-subclass-property-in-category). Custom properties can be added to the class
definition which is not overwritten when the model changes.

Comment: Very interesting! I'll try it out and report back!

Comment: @Mikael: I haven't used MagicalRecord yet. Does it allow to add custom properties to the managed object subclasses? I cannot see that from the documentation or the header files.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
@synthesize downloadErrorCounter = _downloadErrorCounter;
...
```

in @implementation. Note, not @dynamic.

Comment: It should only be noted that if you change the model and let Xcode create new class files, the implementation file is overwritten and your changes are lost.

Comment: @Kjuly, why not use "@dynamic" in this case?

Comment: @Mikael take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160498/synthesize-vs-dynamic-what-are-the-differences :)

Comment: Why are we adding this @synthesize ? Please explain.

Comment: @SanjithBravoDastan __"use the synthesize statement in a class’s implementation block to tell the compiler to create implementations that match the specification you gave in the property declaration."__ u can just search the Apple Doc about it. Btw, w/ latest compiler, it doesn't need any more.

Comment: @Kjuly Thank you.

Comment: @SanjithBravoDastan pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

When trying to use the `@synthesize` solution i got the error:

```
@synthesize not allowed in a category's implementation.
```

Solution was to use associated objects as described in this blog: http://kaspermunck.github.io/2012/11/adding-properties-to-objective-c-categories/

MyManagedObject+Additions.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *test;
```

MyManagedObject+Additions.m

```
NSString const *key = @"my.very.unique.key";

- (void)setTest:(NSString *)test
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &key, test, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (NSString *)test
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &key);
}
```