# Objective C NSPredicate sum of two properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, sum, operators, nspredicate

I'm Trying to create a NSPredicate what can do the sum of two properties and compare it to another property of an object:

Object.property1 + Object.property2 < Object.property3

I tried (%K + %K) < %K but with no success.

PS: Should work even some of properties are null.

I'm trying to avoid making a lot of compound predicates.

Thanks,
Florin

Comment: I think it would be much easier if you add a computed property: `@property (nonatomic, assign), NSIntegerOrDoubleOrWhatever property4;` `-(NSIntegerOrDoubleOrWhatever)property4 {return self.property1 + self.property2;}`, then the format is `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K < %@", @"property4", @(property3)]`

Comment: This will be optimal but my current code structure does not supports that , it's a Core Data fetch what i have to do .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063965/nsmanagedobject-subclass-property-in-category You should be able to do so. It's been a while since I played with CoreData, but the answer seems legit.

Comment: You suggest to use Transient property, i already tried this but Apple says : "You cannot fetch using a predicate based on transient properties (although you can use transient properties to filter in memory yourself)." "Core Data Programming Guide"

Comment: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K + %K) < %K", prop1Name, prop2Name, prop3Name]` should work – is that what you tried?

Comment: @MartinR Exactly this but is fails when one or more properties are nil.

Comment: @FlorinDobjenschi: What do you expect for objects with nil properties? Should they be included in the result set or not?

Comment: @MartinR I want only objects that respect (%K + %K) < %K", prop1Name, prop2Name, prop3Name. One or more properties(prop1Name,prop2Name) may be nil... Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the predicate `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K + %K) < %K", @"a", @"b", @"c"]` returns all objects for which all three properties a, b, c have a value, *and* those values satisfy `a + b < c`. – Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: example of Object: 
Object.prop1 = 1
Object.prop2 = null
Object.prop3 = 3
When appling (%K + %K) < %K", prop1Name, prop2Name, prop3Name the request should return above object but is not in the response if i make prop2 = 0 instead of nil the request is returning the object above. Currently my db has null values on some objects for .prop1 and .prop2 .

Comment: So you want undefined (null)  values treated as zero?

Comment: Yep, if possible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using a SQLite persistent store, the fetch predicate is converted into an equivalent SQLite WHERE clause.  The handling of NULL values is therefore determined by SQLite.  From the [SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/nulls.html):

> Adding anything to null gives null

so if any of the attributes in your predicate is NULL, the sum will be NULL.  The [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW1) is also explicit that NULL values must be tested separately:

> A comparison predicate does not match any value with null except null (nil) or the NSNull null value .... If you want to match null values, you must include a specific test in addition to other comparisons ...

You are therefore faced with having to explicitly test for null values in your predicate, as @Kamil.S has done in his answer.  There is one way to make it slightly easier to read and handle: replace the property values with a conditional expression (equivalent to `property1 == nil ? 0 : property1`).  You can do this with `NSExpression` ([see documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression)):

```
NSExpression *prop1 = [NSExpression expressionForConditional:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"property1 == nil"] 
                                    trueExpression: [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue: @0] 
                                    falseExpression: [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"property1"]];
```

(and similarly for `property2`, etc).  You can then substitute these `NSExpression` values into your predicate using the `%@` format specifier:

```
fetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ + %@ < %@", prop1, prop2, prop3];
```

CoreData parses the conditional expression into a SQLite `CASE (...) when 1 then (...) else (...) END` clause which is evaluated in the database as part of the fetch: but I have no idea how performant that will be compared to the lengthy compound predicate.  (I have also only tested using a single conditional expression; I assume CoreData can handle two or more in a single predicate, but leave it for you to confirm.)

Comment: Thank you , this is what i looking for, as i said in the first post to avoid making a lot of compound predicates. I changed the code i run the tests and is passing .

Answer (score 0):

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                  @"(%K==nil AND %K==nil AND %K!=nil AND 0 < %K) OR"
                   "(%K==nil AND %K==nil AND %K!=nil AND %K < 0) OR"
                   "(%K==nil AND %K==nil AND %K!=nil AND %K < 0) OR"

                   "(%K==nil AND %K!=nil AND %K!=nil AND %K < %K) OR"
                   "(%K==nil AND %K!=nil AND %K!=nil AND %K < %K) OR"
                   "(%K==nil AND %K!=nil AND %K!=nil AND (%K + %K) < 0) OR"

                   "(%K!=nil AND %K!=nil AND %K!=nil AND (%K + %K < %K))",

                   @"property1",@"property2",@"property3",@"property3",
                   @"property3",@"property1",@"property2",@"property2",
                   @"property3",@"property2",@"property1",@"property1",

                   @"property1",@"property2",@"property3",@"property2",@"property3",
                   @"property2",@"property1",@"property3",@"property1",@"property3",
                   @"property3",@"property1",@"property2",@"property1",@"property2",

                   @"property1",@"property2",@"property3",@"property1",@"property2",@"property3"
                   ];
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me but seems predicateWithBlock can not be used on core data , i receive an error : CoreData: error: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x60c000193590> , Problem with subpredicate BLOCKPREDICATE(0x10c5638c0) with userInfo of (null) . Also more info in here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543208/nsfetchrequest-and-predicatewithblock

Comment: Edited my answer with new approach