# Using Objective-C Dynamic properties with generic setter and ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, automatic-ref-counting

I would like to use dynamic properties with generic getter/setter, but it seems that in some cases ARC releases an object when it should not. I give here the simplest code to show the problem.

### Code that works:

I have the class Person with one dynamic property 'name'

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@end
```

In the implementation, the 2 methods have the minimal code to be able to set the person's name. I removed the getter part of the code.

```
@implementation Person

@dynamic name;

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    // Setter signature for a NSString
    return [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:"v@:@"];
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation
{
    // Get the NSString to set
    NSString *s;
    [invocation getArgument:&s atIndex:2];

    NSLog(@"The string is: %@",s);
}

@end
```

In my UIViewController, I have one button:

```
- (IBAction)OnTestClicked:(id)sender
{
    Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
    p.name = @"John Doe";
}
```

and the test works just fine. I got the Log

> The string is: John Doe

If I click the button 10 times, I have 10 times the correct Log

### The Problem

If the value **@"John Doe"** is not a string literal, the app will crash when I click the test button a second time.

Here is an example using a private property 'defaultName' that does not use a string literal.

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *defaultName;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.defaultName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"John Doe"];
}

- (IBAction)OnTestClicked:(id)sender
{
    Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
    p.name = self.defaultName;
}
```

If a click the test button more than once, I got the messages

> malloc: *** error for object 0xa8257b0: pointer being freed was not allocated

or

> malloc: *** error for object 0x8f68430: double free

It seems that ARC is releasing the strong property 'DefaultName'. But because I am using ARC, I cannot add a retain in the setter....

How do I solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: The simple solution would be *use synthesize* with `NSObject` subclasses. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160498/synthesize-vs-dynamic-what-are-the-differences) However, I think you might be trying to do something special here? Why are you wanting to use dynamic here at all? The only purposeful use case I've seen for `dynamic` is with `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

Comment: What happens if you do `p.name = [self.defaultName copy];`

Comment: Yes JRG-Developer, I try to implement my own managed objects. And nhgrif, for the copy, it is not the best solution for big objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `__unsafe_unretained` should solve the problem:

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation
{
    // Get the NSString to set
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *s;
    [invocation getArgument:&s atIndex:2];

    NSLog(@"The string is: %@",s);
}
```

because `getArgument:` just copies the argument into the given buffer, without 
retaining it.