# Why doesn't the object retain its value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I got some problems with my properties of NSManagedObject(UserInformations)

In the second method I request the value of the `userGender` which I set in the method before. But why doesn't `userGender` keep his value?

UserInformations.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@interface UserInformations : NSManagedObject
...
@property (nonatomic) int32_t userGender;
```

UserInformations.m

```
@dynamic userGender;
```

Thats my Viewcontroller:

GenderViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class UserInformations;
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) UserInformations *item;
```

GenderViewController.m

...

```
@synthesize item;
```

...

```
- (IBAction)pickedFemale:(id)sender {

    StoreThem *st = [[StoreThem alloc] init];


    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [st managedObjectContext];
    item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserInfos"
                                inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSNumber *someNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
    [item setValue:someNumber forKey:@"userGender"];
    NSLog(@"%d", [item userGender]);
    //NSLog says 3  
}


- (IBAction)nextView:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"%d", [item userGender]);
    //NSLogs says 0
    if ([item userGender] == 0) {
        return;
    }

                   InfoViewController *mvc = [[InfoViewController alloc] init];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];


}
```

Comment: Have you checked if `item != nil`?

Comment: Just checked it:     if (item != nil) {
        NSLog(@"yolo");
    }
Gives out yolo

Comment: Your code seems a bit unclear to me. Why do you use key value coding? Just do `item.userGender = 3;`. Also, your `UserInformation` model expects an `int`. What you are passing in is an `NSNumber`. And you should save your `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Comment: Thats what i wrote before but then I tried to do it with NSNumber. So it doesn't change anything

Comment: Can you upload your source somewhere? Github?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your code.You have used @dynamic userGender;replace it with @synthesize userGender and use (nonatomic). Please go through that will help you to understand the difference.

[@synthesize vs @dynamic, what are the differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160498/synthesize-vs-dynamic-what-are-the-differences)

Comment: its a integer i can't use strong

Comment: use @synthesize in place of dynamic.

Comment: if(!item)
{ 
item = [[UserInformations alloc]init];
}

 item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserInfos"
                                inManagedObjectContext:context];

Comment: Why should it? What's the difference?

Comment: I thought its no possible to use init with a NSManagedObject. I think you could only use `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` and thats what i did with NSEntityDescription. Your code gives an error: `CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'UserInformations'`

Comment: Ok i solved my problem by choosing a strong reference for `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *context;`

Thanks guys!