# What are the side effects of calling [super loadView]

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, loadview

In the docs for `loadView`, Apple states:

> Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.

So I tried calling `[super loadView]` in my `loadView` method. Nothing bad seemed to happen and there was no warning. I'm using a view created programatically, in `loadView`, not from a NIB.

What (if any) bad things actually happen when I call `[super loadView]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `[super loadView]` will cause the `UIViewController` implementation of `loadView` to run. Among other things, this is the method that loads a view from a NIB, if a `nibName` has been provided. So if you were to call super last, it might overwrite all the view setup you did in your own subclass. If you call super first, this wouldn't be a problem... unless you have any code in `-awakeFromNib` or something.

Basically, you shouldn't call `super` because if you're loading your view programmatically, none of the work done in the superclass is work you want to keep. At best, you're throwing away a bunch of work. At worst, `UIViewController` may set up some state in there that makes assumptions about the origin of the view.

You don't need it, so don't do it.

Comment: What about in the case where you want to add additional subviews to the default view added in a UIViewController - wouldn't it be better to call `[super loadView]` first, to make sure the superview is there, and *then* add your own subviews (assuming IB isn't being used)

Comment: You could do that. The default view of a `UIViewController` is just a plain old `UIView`, so it doesn't gain you a lot, but it's possible. You could also add those in `-viewDidLoad`

Comment: Yep - Previously I would have added them in viewDidLoad but I'm now starting to prefer doing so in load view, so the view is built sooner

Answer (score 1):

If you allow me this comparison, it's like "Don't cross the street on red."

There is a traffic light that establishes a rule *not* to cross the street because it *might* be dangerous whatever the reasons. It is perfectly plausible that you might cross the street on red and nothing happens.

The API sets up the is rule by stating you should *not* call super. Like in the example above, the outcome is undetermined and depends on other things. It is perfectly plausible that nothing happens.