# loadView() no called

Tags: ios, objective-c, nimbus-ios

I have a UIViewController calling another view Controller with a defined loadView method. I’ve been trying many options without success to solve the problem of the loadView method not called.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.
MArcos

Caller UIViewController

```
#import "MyAlbumViewController.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

implementation

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    UIViewController*albumVC = [[MyAlbumViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:albumVC animated:YES];


}
@end
```

Called UIViewController

```
@interface MyAlbumViewController : NIToolbarPhotoViewController <NIPhotoAlbumScrollViewDataSource>

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "MyAlbumViewController.h"

@implementation MyAlbumViewController

- (void)loadView{

    [super loadView];

    self.photoAlbumView.dataSource = self;

    // Set the default loading image.
    self.photoAlbumView.loadingImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
                                        NIPathForBundleResource(nil, @"NimbusPhotos.bundle/gfx/default.png")];

    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Loading...", @"Navigation bar title - Loading a photo album");

    [self loadAlbumInformation];
}...
```

Comment: Why are you using loadView instead of viewDidLoad?

Comment: this a programmatically view from the Nimbus iOS framework.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788928/loadview-functions-in-uiview-ios for a discussion about loadView

Comment: Yes , if your are using a programmatically view , using loadView is very good . I think may be your self.navigationController = nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of `loadView` is to completely override the method, and not call `super`

What you are doing is exactly what the `viewDidLoad` method is for, it doesn't matter if you loaded it from a nib file or whatever

And I quote from your own post, in your `ViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}
```

Comment: If my called UIViewController has a programmatically defined view, should I load the view from loadView or I'm wrong?

Comment: It's not necessary to use the `loadView`. You can even create things in your `viewDidLoad` like adding a table or some buttons or whatever, because that method is called right after loadView and only when it was just created, I do it all the time :)

Comment: I've just added a NSLog inside the viewDidLoad and no result was displayed. Also the viewDidLoad has not been called. It seems that I'm doing something wrong with the [self.navigationController pushViewController:albumVC animated:YES];

Comment: I changed from [self.navigationController pushViewController:albumVC animated:YES];   to [self presentViewController:albumVC animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: and now its calling the loadView() and also the viewDidLoad().

Answer (score 0):

I was pushing view controller with:

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:albumVC animated:YES];
```

I just changed to:

```
[self presentViewController:albumVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

UIViewController Navigation Controller

> navigationController The nearest ancestor in the view controller
>   hierarchy that is a navigation controller. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UINavigationController
>   *navigationController Discussion If the receiver or one of its ancestors is a child of a navigation controller, this property
>   contains the owning navigation controller. This property is nil if the
>   view controller is not embedded inside a navigation controller.