# How to add self sizing child UICollectionViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a view controller which has a container view.

I would like to add a `UICollectionViewController` as a child view controller i.e., add the view of the `UICollectionViewController` as a subview of the container view and call `didMove(toParent:)`.

I would like the height of the container view to be dynamic so that it depends on the height of the `UICollectionViewController`'s view. I want the height `UICollectionView` to be equal to its content height.

Can anyone point out how to do this?

This is what I have done till now-

While adding the `UICollectionViewController`, set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false, as given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35431534.

```
let viewController = CustomCollectionViewController()
viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
addChild(viewController)
containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
viewController.didMove(toParent: self)

viewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
viewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
viewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
viewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

I created a custom `UICollectionView` such that its height depends on its content size as given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49297382.

```
class CustomCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
    }
}
```

Set the above custom `UICollectionView` as the collectionView of the `CustomCollectionViewController` using the answer given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41404946

```
class CustomCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        collectionView = CustomCollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout)
    }
}
```

What I have done does not work. Can anyone point out how to do this?

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Comment: no. i could not figure it out